# Union Intersection Test

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am trying to understand the union intersection test shown in my class. Originally we were attempting to test for $X_i\sim  N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ that $H_0:\mu=u_o$ the professor proposed an equivalent test
$H_o: \cap_{a\in\mathbb{R}^p}\{a^t\mu=a^t\mu_0\}$ vs the alternative of just finding one $a$ such that this does not hold. She mentioned that we must be mindful of accounting for multiple comparison tests and want to control for error. That  is we want to make sure that $P(\cup_{a\in\mathbb{R}^p}|\frac{\sqrt{n}a^{T}(\bar{X}-\mu)}{\sqrt{a^{T}Sa}}|>c)\le \alpha$ which are the  rejection regions for the t-tests resulting from the projection using $a$. Then she stated something that made no sense to me she said that this is equivalent to $P\bigg(\underset{a\in\mathbb{R}^p}{\text{sup}}|\frac{\sqrt{n}a^{T}(\bar{X}-\mu)}{\sqrt{a^{T}Sa}}|>c\bigg)$. I can't see how these probabilities are equivalent. The only sense I can make of this is that the equivalency follows from instead of testing multiple tests we are going to find one such $a$ that we can reject therefore we can reject the null. That is we are only going to perform one test using the sup as our projection and we can control type 1 error. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(\omega,a):=\left|\sqrt{n}a^{\top}(\bar{X}_n(\omega)-\mu)/\sqrt{a^{\top}S_n(\omega)a}\right|$, and let
\begin{align}
A&:=\bigcup_{a\in \mathbb{R}^p}\{\omega:f(\omega,a)>c\} \quad\text{and} \\
B&:=\left\{\omega:\sup_{a\in\mathbb{R}^p}f(\omega,a)>c\right\}.
\end{align}
If $\omega\in A$, then $\exists a'$ s.t. $f(\omega,a')>c$. This means that $\sup_{a\in\mathbb{R}^p}f(\omega,a)\ge f(\omega,a')>c$, i.e., $\omega\in B$. This proves the first inclusion, $A\subseteq B$. On the other hand, when $\omega\in B$, $\exists a''$ s.t. $f(\omega,a'')>c$ so that $\omega\in A$ (*note that we couldn't conclude that if we used the weak inequality instead*). This proves the second inclusion, $B\subseteq A$. Combining both inclusions, we get $A=B$.